# jquery fadeout not working on ipad landscape for responsive dropdown navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this responsive navigation menu. the fade out on dropdown does not work on ipad landscape and some times some li from the dropdown disappear also on ipad landscape. other question is how could i disable the fadout when the screen is 800px or less?

Html5:

```
<div class="mainWrap">      
<a id="touch-menu" class="mobile-menu"><i class="icon-reorder"></i>Menu</a>
<nav>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a class="active" href="index.html"><i class="icon-home"></i>INICIO</a>
<li><a href="nosotros.html"><i class="icon-user"></i>NOSOTROS</a></li>
<li class="point"><a id="menu-programas"><i class="icon-folder-open"></li>PROGRAMAS</a>
<ul class="programas">
<li><a href="programas/hidrogym.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>Hidrogym</a></li>
<li><a href="programas/natacion.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right</li>Nataci&oacute;n</a></li>
<li><a href="programas/buceo.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>Buceo</a></li>
<li><a href="programas/hidroterapia.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>Hidroterapia</a></li>
<li><a href="programas/preparto.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>Trabajo Preparto</a></li>                     
<li><a href="programas/salvamento.html"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>Salvamento y rescate</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="point" onClick="window.location.href='index.html#lateral';"><a><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>CONTACTO</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var touch   = $('#touch-menu');
var menu    = $('.menu');
var ptouch  = $('#menu-programas');
var pmenu   = $('.programas');

$(touch).on('click', function(e) {
event.preventDefault();
menu.slideToggle();
})  

$(ptouch).on('click', function(e) {
event.preventDefault();
pmenu.slideToggle();
})

$('.point').hover(function () {
$(this).children('.programas').hide();
}, function () {
$(this).children('.programas').stop().hide();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
var w = $(window).width();
if(w >= 800 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
menu.removeAttr('style');
}
});

});
```

CSS3:

```
margin:0 auto; 
width:100%;
}
nav{
background:#fff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0066CC;
border-top: 1px solid #0066CC;
margin-bottom: 2em;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.menu{
display:block;
}
.menu li{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
z-index:100;}
.menu li:first-child{margin:0;}
.menu li a{
color:#0066CC;
display:block;
font-weight:600;
padding:0.8em;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.menu li .active{
color: #FF0000;
}
.menu li a:hover{
color: #FF0000;
}
.menu .point:hover{
cursor:pointer;
}
.menu .programas a.active{
color:#FF0000;
}
.menu .programas a:hover{
color:#FF0000;
}
.menu .programas{
background: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #0066CC;
display: none;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
text-indent: 1.5em;
width: 14em;
z-index: 100;
}
.menu .programas li{
background:none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0066CC;
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
z-index: 100;
}
.menu .programas li:last-child{
border-bottom: none;
}
.menu .programas li a{
background:#ffffff;
color:#0066CC;
display:block;
font-size:0.9em;
font-weight:normal;
}
.mobile-menu{
background:#FFF;
border-top: 1px solid #0066CC;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0066CC;
color:#0066CC;
display:none; 
font-weight:600;
width:100%;
padding:0.8em 0;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-indent: 0.8em;
}
.mobile-menu:hover{
color:#0066CC;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
.menu{
display: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.mobile-menu{
display: block; 
cursor: pointer;
text-align: left;
}
nav{
background: none;
border-bottom: none;
border-top: none;
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.menu li{
display: block;
margin: 0;
}
.menu li a 
{background: #ffffff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0066CC;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
color: #0066CC;
}
.menu .programas{
border: none;
display: none;
left: 0;
position: relative;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
} 
.menu .programas  li{
border: none;
}
}
```

Comment: Just as a heads up `$(touch).on('click', function(e) {
event.preventDefault();
menu.slideToggle();
});` the `(e)` should match `event`

Comment: And you have some syntax errors... the `$(touch)` and `$(ptouch)` are missing `;` at the end

Comment: And again, you are missing a `>` on one of the `<icon>` elements in your html... All these little things make browsers act all quirky. Some can reconcile the errors, some can't.

Comment: thanks @VIDesignz i corrected code, but still the same.